# Adding image logo to bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, css, image, bootstrap-modal, carousel

As I try to add a logo image to the carousel, I have a hard time making sure the logo remains stationary at all times without moving inside the carousel.

```
<!--logo-->
<div class="logo-image">
    <img src="Aaron%20Murillo-Black.png" class="img-fluid">
</div>
<!--Carousel image slider-->
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="logo-image">
            <img src="Aaron%20Murillo-Black.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Web Site Logo">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="Dress.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="Dress">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="Balloon.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="Balloon Fiesta">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="DarkChurch.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="Dark Church">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="River%20Falls.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="River Cave">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="Wedding.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="Couples">
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

all my css with this had been a bust.

```
.logo-image{
    width: 10%;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 10%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I'm not getting you wrong you want to make the logo stationary and not moving as the carousel moves ?
You could do this in the CSS, by:

Giving the carousel a position of relative and the logo that of absolute

Answer (score 0):

Wrap all your code with div and make it relative then make .logo-image absolute, it will make your logo remain still

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
}
.logo-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <!--logo-->
  <div class="logo-image">
      <img src="Aaron%20Murillo-Black.png" class="img-fluid">
  </div>
  <!--Carousel image slider-->
  <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="logo-image">
              <img src="Aaron%20Murillo-Black.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Web Site Logo">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item active">
              <img src="Dress.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="Dress">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="Balloon.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="Balloon Fiesta">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="DarkChurch.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="Dark Church">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="River%20Falls.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="River Cave">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="Wedding.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="Couples">
          </div>
      </div>
      <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </button>
      <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </button>
  </div>
</div>
```